# Access, Between clause with date of previous year

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, between

The following query calculates sales data on a monthly basis for the current year. I would like to modify the query to make it return the same monthly sales data but for the previous year.

The BETWEEN clause in the second last line of code sets it for the current year. Is there a way to modify the BETWEEN clause to set it for the previous year from Jan. 1 thru Dec. 31?

```
SELECT Format(DatePart("m",months.month_start),"00") & "/" & Year(months.month_start) AS [Month/Year], 

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) ,2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS [Gross Sales],

(SELECT   Round(Nz(Sum((Nz(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE,0))*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS COGS,

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) - Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM INVENTORY  INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS [Sales Margin], 

Round((((SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0) - Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM INVENTORY  INNER JOIN SALES_RECEIPT ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end)/(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE * sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)  FROM SALES_RECEIPT INNER JOIN INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = SALES_RECEIPT.INVENTORY_ID WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.[SALE_DATE] between months.month_start and months.month_end))*100),0) & "%" AS [Profit Margin], (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * deductions_inventory.quantity), 0),2) FROM INVENTORY INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID WHERE DEDUCTIONS_INVENTORY.ENTRY_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS [Inventory Deductions], (SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(inventory.VENDOR_ACTUAL_PRICE * DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.quantity), 0),2) FROM INVENTORY INNER JOIN DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.INVENTORY_ID WHERE DEDUCTIONS_EXPENSE.ENTRY_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS [Inventory Expenses],

(SELECT Round(Nz(Sum(returns.selling_price * returns.quantity), 0),2)
FROM returns inner JOIN inventory ON INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID = returns.INVENTORY_ID
WHERE returns.return_date between months.month_start and months.month_end) AS [Sales Returns]

FROM
 (SELECT DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), 1) AS month_start,
  DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date) + 1, 1)) AS month_end

FROM SALES_RECEIPT WHERE sale_date between #1/1# And #12/31#
GROUP BY Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date))  AS months;
```

Comment: I don't know access, reading this http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/dateadd.php it should be something like:
... between DateAdd("yyyy", -1, #1/1#) And DateAdd("yyyy", -1, #12/31#)

Comment: That worked!  Thank you for the information!